# Redirect Python Print & Input Calls to ConEmu (or similar program)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, unicode

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

Printing unicode character `\u0332` to command prompt with python results in an underscore after the previous letter, not underneath.

I ran `chcp 65001` based on some suggestions I found on the web, it displays properly neither before nor after running that command.

**Example:**

```
C:\>python
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 22:39:24) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print(u"this is a te\u0332st.")
this is a te_st.
```

**Expected output:**

`this is a te̲st.`

(note: copy pasting the output from console to here displays the character correctly, as seen in expected output)

**EDIT 1:**

It seems that no unicode combine characters are displaying combined in the command prompt.

**NEW QUESTION BASED ON COMMENTS BY @ErykSun**

Is there a simple way to either redirect python print and input calls to ConEmu (or similar program), or write custom functions that replace them?

**EDIT 1:**

Based on the suggestion from @lenz, is there a way to run ConEmu and pass it a command to run from a command?

Comment: I don't think the Windows console can do that. Just try it with a simple `echo [your text]`.

Comment: I don't think that will help as the console *is* displaying the unicode character (just not under the letter), however I'll still try it. I know for a fact that `\u0332` is Python's way of expressing that unicode character but I think cmd uses a different method, gimme a sec to look it up.

Comment: @usr2564301 I can get the command prompt to echo the character fine, it just appears next to, rather than under, a letter.

Comment: A console session is hosted by conhost.exe, which serves multiple attached clients, including cmd.exe, powershell.exe, and python.exe. By default, the host also provides a terminal window for the user interface. This default window is limited to displaying characters in the Unicode BMP, with no support for combining codes or automatic font fallback. The good news is that you can use an alternative terminal window instead of the default window -- such as ConEmu or the new "Windows Terminal" app (beta).

Comment: Fun fact: Windows 10 introduced [ConPTY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/pseudoconsoles) pseudoconsole support, which makes implementing a different terminal for console sessions much easier to implement. It used to require tedious buffer scraping and API hooking.

Comment: @ErykSun Is there a simple way to automatically redirect python print calls to ConEmu? (edit: and input calls)

Comment: I think the easier solution is to start Python from ConEmu.

Comment: @lenz I want to run the script from anywhere, not just from cmd.exe. A workaround could be to get the script to check if its running inside ConEmu, and if not, run itself from ConEmu.

Comment: @100pxsquared, it's up to the user to choose a different terminal such as ConEmu. IIRC ConEmu can set up session-wide hooks to make itself the default terminal (e.g. if the user runs "python.exe" from the Win+R run dialog). The new Windows Terminal app doesn't have that ability yet. It's also still in beta and apparently doesn't yet support rendering this U+0332 combining code to get an underlined character (at least not the version I have installed).

Comment: @ErykSun Am I correct assuming setting ConEmu as the default terminal would mean double clicking a python script that's been told to open with `python.exe` would be run in ConEmu? Or would i need to set the default program to open `.py` files with to ConEmu?

Comment: It should work. IIRC, this trick is based on API hooking, so when python.exe tries to allocate a console for itself, it will actually load ConEmu. This is what I recall at least. I don't use ConEmu on a daily basis, so I'd have to install it and verify.

Comment: By the way, there is no need to set the input and output codepages to 65001 (UTF-8) with Python 3.6+. As cmd.exe has done for almost 30 years, Python 3.6+ uses the console's wide-character API for standard I/O, which is UTF-16 and supports the full range of Unicode (at least at the API level; the default terminal, as discussed here, still has very bad support for Unicode). Also, for legacy applications that do use the codepages with byte strings, setting the input codepage to UTF-8 is broken at the API level. It limits input to 7-bit ASCII, which is practically useless.

Comment: @ErykSun Working! Do you want to post the answer yourself or am I ok doing it? (edit: ConEmu is now my default terminal)

Comment: You have it installed and tested, so by all means write up an answer for what you did to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ErykSun's comments, I've set my default terminal to ConEmu which displays unicode combined character correctly.

To future users looking for an answer to this question, assuming you're using ConEmu you can set it to the default console by doing this:

right click the top bar and go to `Settings...` (or use the keyboard shortcut Win+Alt+P)

go to `Intergration -> Default term` in the left menu

Check the following boxes:

`Force ConEmu as default terminal for console applications`, `Register on OS startup`, `Leave in TSA`, and `Aggressive mode`

Then hit `Save settings`